# Multiple MX DNS entries for mail server backup / redundancy?

Tags: networking, dns, mail-server, self-hosting

I have set up MX records for my domain as follows:

```
0 mail1.mydomain.com.
10 mail2.mydomain.com.
20 mail1.backupmxserver.com.
30 mail2.backupmxserver.com.
```

where entries 0 and 10 are for mail servers with static IP addresses that I host at home. Entries 20 and 30 are for two 'Backup MX' servers I pay someone to maintain on the internet, which forward any mail they receive to one of the first two servers, retrying indefinitely if/as necessary.

The goal behind setting this up like this is to ensure I don't lose any incoming mail even if both of my home servers are temporarily down or unreliable. I'm assuming that, if both are unreachable, a server on the internet sending mail to my domain will instead try server 20 or 30 as a backup. (And then, once one of my own two are reachable again, the mail will come through, forwarded by the backup server that received it.)

My question, however, is if it is indeed reasonable to assume that a server sending mail to my domain will try server 20 or 30 if needed?

I was told by the company hosting them that, yes, this setup is standard and acceptable.

But are they correct? Can I trust that *every* legitimate server that will try to send me email won't give up after bouncing on just entries 0 and 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's accurate and the expected behaviour for any sending mail servers.

For comparison if you check out the MX records for `gmail.com` you'll see they also have a lot of MX records (though in their case each host likely relates to a collection of servers, rather than an individual one).

```
Non-authoritative answer:
gmail.com       MX preference = 40, mail exchanger = alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 30, mail exchanger = alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
```

The sending mail server receives all the MX records, and then works through the list in priority order until it's able to send the message. In many cases if they're unable to send the message, it will be queued and the server will try again later, but that's down to how the owner of that server has chosen to configure it.

You can also set multiple MX records with the same preference, for instance you could configure it as

```
0 mail1.mydomain.com.
10 mail2.mydomain.com.
20 mail1.backupmxserver.com.
20 mail2.backupmxserver.com.
```

Sending mail servers are still expected to try all of the provided records (up to a configurable limit depending on the setup), but having the two backups with the same preference means that some sending servers will try `mail1` first, and others will try `mail2` first (and then trying the other), distributing the email between the two, rather than all email hitting `mail1` and only reaching `mail2` if that's not available.

As an aside, the one common exception to this can be spammers, who will sometimes aim to deliver their email direct to the last server rather than first. The thinking being that backup mail servers may not get monitored as closely, or have as much in the way of anti-spam services running on them as the primary servers. Of course if your backups are simply holding the email and then relaying it to the primary once online again it doesn't matter.

Comment: Extremely helpful, thank you.

Comment: Clarification, when you say "Sending mail servers are still expected to try all of the provided records (up to a configurable limit depending on the setup...," is there a possibility some sending mail servers will be configured to not attempt the full four?

Comment: Possible yes, but very unlikely, unless the email admin was a nutter who didn't want to successfully deliver emails. For example, hMail defaults to 15, Exim defaults to 5, so with both of those all of your MX records would be attempted.